# Fragments are required to have a parameterless constructor - what if my Fragment needs parameters?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm quoting Google's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html):

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor.
>   The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed,
>   in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this
>   constructor to instantiate it.

What happens if a Fragment needs parameters? Say I created an instance of the fragment using a non-parameterless c'tor and then added the fragment to an Activity.
How would Android know what to upon state restoration? Or am I supposed to manually take care of it (which I probably can't if the parameter was for instance a complex view model)?

Comment: The other thread doesn't really answer how to deal with complex parameters like a view model that cannot be serialized and is created be the owning activity.

Comment: You should mention it in your question that your model cannot be serialized. By the way, what kind of data do you have to pass?

Comment: @fasteque I thought I did. See last sentence. But what is the solution if the parameter cannot be serialized?

Comment: You can set a Parcelable object in the bundle, you can refer to this link to understand how to write a custom class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it a Bundle with the parameters, like so:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment{
   private static final String MY_FIELD = "myfield";


    public static MyFragment newInstance(int param){
        MyFragment result = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(MY_FIELD, param);
        result.setArguments(args);
        return result;
    }


    ...


    private void myMethod(){
        int myField = getArguments.getInt(MY_FIELD);

    }

}
```